# Match Everything Except a Variable String

Tags: regex

I have been able to match all text within a string that looks like the below:

```
[!--$element--]
```

using the below regex:

```
\[!--(.*?)]
```

However, now I want to match everything EXCEPT the above string, but can't seem to get it to work.  I've attempted to use the not `^` expression and the look-ahead `?!` expression, but can't seem to get it right.

For example,

I want

```
This is an [!--$element--]
```

to turn into:

```
[!--$element--]
```

I am using PHPs preg_replace() to remove all text that isn't an `[--$element--]`

Any idea how I can do so?

Comment: Do you mean you want to test, i.e. `[!--$element--]` should result in `false`, or not match, i.e. `one[!--$element--]two` should result in `["one", "two"]`?

Comment: Which language are you using? This would be better accomplished with a positive match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Capture Group, `(*SKIP)(*F)` or Split

To match this, we have several options.

**Option 1: With capture groups**

This is a longer way to do it, but it will work in all engines.

```
\[!--[^-]*--\]|((?:(?!\[!--[^-]*--\]).)+)
```

The strings you want are in Group 1. In **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mU7lT6/4)**, look at the captures in the **right panel**.

**Option 2: (*SKIP)(*F)**

This will only work in Perl and PCRE (and therefore PHP). It matches the strings directly.

```
\[!--[^-]*--\](*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!\[!--[^-]*--\]).)+
```

In **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mU7lT6/5)**, see the matched strings.

**Option 3: Split**

[Match All and Split are Two Sides of the Same Coin](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch), so we can use `preg_split` instead of `preg_match_all`. By splitting the string, we remove the pieces we want to exclude.

```
$element_regex = '~\[!--[^-]*--\]~';
$theText = preg_split($element_regex, $yourstring);
```

**Explanation**

This problem is a classic case of the technique explained in this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)

**Option 1.** In Option 1, The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `[!--$element--]`. We will ignore these matches. The right side matches and captures other text, and we know it is the right ones because it was not matched by the expression on the left.

**Option 2**. In Option 2, the left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `[!--$element--]` then deliberately fails, after which the engine skips to the next position in the string. The right side matches the `this` word you want, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: This does exactly what I want.  Thanks.

Comment: FYI, added a third option with `preg_split`, probably the shortest way to do it. :)

Comment: Another case where the The Best Regex Trick is put into good use. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of replacing the text you don’t want, just grab the text you do want:

```
preg_match_all('/\[!--(.*?)]/', $input, $matches);
$result = implode('', $matches[0]);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MvTdoo)

Comment: I gave zx81 the check because he/she technically answered the question correctly.  However, if I could give two checks I would because I will be using this instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that I didn't used `[!--(.*?)]` because it will also match elements that are different from `[!--$element--]` like `[!--$element]`

```
<?php
$text ='This is an [!--$element--]. Here is some other text';
preg_match_all('#(\[\!--.*--\])#',$text,$out);
print_r($out);
?>
```

And the output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [!--$element--]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => [!--$element--]
        )

)
```

Here is the online **[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/C8wW3I)**

Answer (score 0):

use preg_replace with this pattern [Demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6bi)

```
preg_replace("/(.*)(\[!--.*?])(.?)/", "\1\3", $input_lines);
```